# SQL Как прибавить +1 к цифрах в значении ячейке, где имеются помимо цифр другие знаки

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
UPDATE `scPlayerStats` SET `virtualCrates` = 'BeginnerCrate;0;1' WHERE `scPlayerStats`.`uuid` = (select uuid from TakePerms.luckperms_players where username = 'name')
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при повторном выполнении sql команды в значении "BeginnerCrate;0;1" не перезаписывалось, а складывалось.
Пример: Было "BeginnerCrate;0;1" - после выполнения повторного запроса должно стать "BeginnerCrate;0;2"

Comment: хранить текст отдельно от чисел

Comment: Разделить. Прибавить. Соединить. Если будет проще - поменять хранение на узкую таблицу.